# How to enable all the firewall rules on Azure Application Gateway via Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm preparing a script to change several aspects of an existing Azure Aplication Gateway.  Previously, my team had disabled some of the rules on the WAF.  My intention is to enhact them all again, thus disabling advanced configuration.  I can't find the way to do this via Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

WAF rules are not about App GW, it's a separate feature in the Azure.
So, you should use:

```
Get-AzApplicationGatewayFirewallPolicy | Set-AzApplicationGatewayFirewallPolicy
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/set-azapplicationgatewayfirewallpolicy?view=azps-7.1.0

Also, as an example you can look here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/scripts/waf-custom-rules-powershell#sample-script

Comment: Ok, for what I see here I need to create a brand new Firewall Policy and apply it to my existing Application Gateway.  There is no way to modify the esiting policy?

Comment: Comment for people seeking the same:  I was seeking a Firewall Name in the portal to get the existing policy, modify it, and then associate to the Application Gateway.  What I have in reality is a WAF Configuration.  In that case, if you want to transition from WAF config to WAF policy, you need to follow the steps depicted here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/associate-waf-policy-existing-gateway

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new WAF policy and associated with an existing GW.